# I want to delete the multiple records at the same time from mongo using java code

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, morphia

In my project they have written below line in repository class.

private Datastore datastore; (import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore)

Now from java code I have to delete the multiple records at the same time by passing the list of entity class but it is not working and not giving any error also

Below is the code which I have tried

```
public void deleteData(List<Data> list){

     datastore.delete(Data.class, list);
}
```

So how can I delete the multiple records by hitting db once.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it using `mongoTemplate`.First you should use `query` to filtrate what your want to delete. Such as,`Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("goodsId").is(goodsId));`. Then use `remove()` to delete them. Such as `mongoTemplate.remove(query, Goods.class);`  And I think you should check your mongo config first, if your mongo is cluster-mode, you must make sure you are operating the master db.

Comment: Yeah we have mongoTemplate also but that is in different service.
but this service is legacy service we cannot change the mongo configuration now.
we need to achieve this using Datastore only.
so any other suggestions

Comment: What version of morphia are you using?

Comment: morphia version is 1.2.2

Comment: 1.2.2 is *ages* old.  have you considered updating?  I'll see if I still have that javadoc around.  i'm not sure it's even still online.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  1.2.2 is 5.5 years old now so i'm having to dig *deep* for this so it might not be 100%.  (It's so old I had to fetch the javadoc jar from maven central just to see the docs...)  At any rate, that `delete()` you're calling takes a type and a `List` of IDs.  So to make that work, you'd want to convert that list from the entities to their IDs and then pass that in.  something like `list.stream().map( d -> d.id).collect(Collectors.toList())` might do the trick.  (You may have to finesse that syntax.  I've been writing kotlin all night and that looks slightly different.  :D )